# AttributeError: 'Container' object has no attribute 'manager'

Tags: python, kivy, runtime-error, kivymd

MY CODE:
МОЙ КОД:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemanddock')
Window.size = (480, 853)

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Container(MDGridLayout):
    def scit(self):
        try:
            znach = str(self.text_input.text)
        except:
            znach = 'ничего не введено'

class MyApp(MDApp):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    title = 'Пока что так'

        def build(self):
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
            return Container()
```

MyApp().run()

MY kv.file:
МОЙ kv.файл:

```
WindowManager:
MainWindow:
SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: 'main'
<ItemLabel@MDLabel>:
    font_size: '35sp'
    valign:'middle'
    text_size: self.size
<Container>:
    rows: 30
    padding: [30, 20, 30, 10]
    text_input: text_input

    MDTextField:
        id: text_input
        size_hint: 4, 2.4
        multiline: True
        font_size: '45sp'
        input_type: 'text'
        hint_text: 'Введите продукты здесь'

    FloatLayout:
        MDRaisedButton:
            size_hint: 0.7, 0.6
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'y': 0.2}
            text: 'Найти блюда'
            font_size: '25sp'

            on_release:

                root.scit()
                app.root.current = "second" if text_input.text != "None" else "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

When I press the button error appears:
Когда я нажимаю на кнопку появляется ошибка:
AttributeError: 'Container' object has no attribute 'manager'
Please help me with mistakes in my code if I have them
Пожалуйста помогите мне с ошибками в коде если они есть

Comment: Please translate this question entirely into English, or delete it and post it entirely in Russian on [ru.so]

Answer (score 0):

In your kv rule for `<Container>`, try changing:

```
root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

to:

```
app.root.transition.direction = "left"
```

Within a rule in `kv`, the term `root` refers to the root object of the rule. In this case, that root object is the `Container` instance, which indeed has no `manager` attribute.

Comment: now it appears another error: AttributeError: 'Container' object has no attribute 'transition'

Comment: Your `MyApp.build()` method returns an instance of `Container` as the root of your `App`, so your `App` has no `ScreenManager` and no `Screens`. I suggest you start by removing the `return Container()` from your `build()` method.